# Loading current location in Google Maps is not quick in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to load my current location in Google Maps V2. The problem is that when I load the app I first see the default maps that loads somewhere near africa and then after 1 or 2 sec it animates to the current location. Instead I would like to show my map directly to current location something like Google maps or Uber does.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Here is what I have done:

The initMap() is called in onCreateView in Fragment.

```
private boolean initMap() 
{
    if (googleMap == null)
    {
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        googleMap = mapFrag.getMap();
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

        if (friendslocationclicked == false)
        {
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
          googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude()), ZOOMVALUE));
          googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude())).title("It's Me!"));
      }
     });
  }

    return (googleMap != null);
}
```

Can somebody help me fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Just check if your GPS is enabled?? And if your location is 0.0 then it will show you africa by default and when you enable GPS then it takes 2-3 minutes to navigate your current location. So also call your function in `onResume()` method.

Comment: I have manually set the co-ordinates to show india on startup....

Comment: How is Google Maps or Uber map are doing it? when I load Google Maps i immediately get my location? It is instant?

Comment: @Toppers: That wouldn't work for my app because I would like to get the current location automatically and move the camera where ever required.

Comment: yes it'll initiate with India. Sorry I am not sure about the way Uber handles it...

Comment: @Toppers - No Worries.. Check Google maps. Load the app it would immediately take you to your current location.

Comment: try using moveCamera instead of animateCamera

Comment: @MarcelKrivek. It is the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Instead of using:-


animateCamera()
```

use:-
    moveCamera()
    e.g:-

```
 googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude()), 14.0f));
```